# Would a ice core samples taken on the Moon provide us with information about the past that we cannot easily obtain in other ways?

Tags: the-moon, planetary-science, sample-return, ice

[This article](https://science.nasa.gov/solar-system/moon/10-things-what-we-learn-about-earth-by-studying-the-moon/) on NASA's website describes 10 things we’ve learned about Earth by studying the Moon, including the makeup of a newborn Earth and potential clues to how life began on Earth. The [Clementine imaging experiment](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/clementine.html) showed that ice exists in the permanently shadowed areas at the bottom of deep craters near the Moon's south pole. Presumably, it might be possible to take ice-core samples there. Would these samples contain preserved information about our past that we cannot obtain in other ways, such as by studying ice-core samples taken here on Earth or by analyzing the lunar samples brought back by Apollo?

[image]